# JLabel on JPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I am trying to print a `JLabel` on top of a `JPanel`, but I find when I run the program I can only see one or the other. If I put `add(Panel)` first then I will only see the label and vice versa. I've been at this for hours, but just can't seem to figure it out.

Can somone please tell me what's wrong?

### `Jframe`

```
public Jframe()
{
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Snakey Snake Snake") ;
    l.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);;
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    l.setVisible(true);
    l.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    l.setTrans(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBackground(Color.red);

    Panels p = new Panels();
    frame.add(l);
    frame.add(p)
}
```

### `Panels`

```
public class Panels extends JPanel {

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 100);
}
```

Comment: Hint: `Jframe` and `Panels` are really bad names for classes, since they might cause confusion (already used name and plural should be avoided)...

Comment: Try `frame.add(l,BorderLayout.NORTH);` , because by default for `JFrame`, the layout manager is a `BorderLayout` and `add` will add to `BorderLayout.CENTER` , and only one component can be at this place.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).